# Good resource of maths problems with solutions

Tags: reference-request, inequality, induction, divisibility, online-resources

I'm searching for a good book or web page that has a good amount of problems and their solutions, at undergraduate level, of divisibility, inequalities, induction, etc.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

*[Problem Solving Strategies](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387982191)* by Arthur Engel.

Comment: Thanks, i've seen it and it looks like it has a lot of problems and their solutions. But i will wait till someone propose better resources to that specific subjects, if there are any